# How can I make a hover with content on a div hover?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

hi i want to make a effect like this to my div on a hover:
[website with the effect, hover over the people div's to see](http://www.dvan.nl/over-ons/onze-mensen/)

I have tried to make a grid but I am strugling to get the hover effect on top of the div.

[`my codepen link, need the hover on the blocks`](http://codepen.io/amirhanif/pen/wgVRNQ?editors=1100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a container div and at least one foreground div to cover the background (could be just an image). Then you'll want to target the parent on hover and change the foreground child. I used `transform` instead of animating a position property because it's more performant.

```css
.card{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.card > div{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.card .foreground{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform:translateX(100%);
  background-color:blue;
  transition:.5s ease;
}

.card:hover .foreground{
  transform:translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="foreground"></div>
   <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can attach styles to a div by using the :hover keyword.

Example, you want to change some effect on the div on hover:

```
div:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

You want to change some effect on a child, on parent hover

```
div:hover .child {
    background-color: black;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, check the class changes when you force hover on their page, their original element has these styles:

```
z-index: 200;
content: "";
height: 263px;
width: 102px;
background-color: #91c6c2;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: -50px;
-webkit-transform: skew(21deg);
transform: skew(21deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: right 0.5s;
transition: right 0.5s;
```

On hover, they just change the elements "right", to 80px, which makes it float in via the mentioned transition, "transition: right 0.5s".

Comment: this is not what i mean, i need to get the effect of the website that you saw in the link , to have the same effect but it is an overloy over a div and i dont know how i can call the overlay div to show on hover of the div.

Answer (score 2):

you require a overlay effect on hover of a div.
Please refer this [link](http://codepen.io/felicia/pen/qKhJt)

```
 <div id="overlay">
    <span id="plus">+</span>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay    {  background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
               text-align:center;
               padding:45px 0 66px 0;
               opacity:0;
               -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;}

#box:hover #overlay {
               opacity:1;}

#plus       {  font-family:Helvetica;
               font-weight:900;
               color:rgba(255,255,255,.85);
               font-size:96px;}
```

Found this in google search and also lots of plugins are avila

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way but it was most definitely the easiest that I've found. You can add the absolute position to the hidden div to make it on top of the image if you so choose!

HTML:

```
<div id='backgroundImg' onmouseover="hoverOver('show');" onmouseout="hoverOver('hide');">
     <div id='hiddenDiv'> 

     </div>
     <img src='myImage.png'>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<style>
    function hoverOver(type) {
        if (type=='show') {
            document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display='inherit';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display='none';
        }
    }
</style>
```